# MySQL Avarage Execution Time For Query and Relative and Absolute error in measurement

Tags: mysql

What is best way to execute same query 100 times and get all that query execution time and after that to get avarage time. I don't want to start same query 100 times. And after that i want to count also relative and absolute error in measurement.

Comment: MYSQL probably caches the query the first time. Are you looking for ways to defeat that so you get real results?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey no, i will shut down caching, i want first to measure time without indexed fields and after that with index

Comment: If the index makes a difference, you won't need 100 queries to see it

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs the SQL_NO_CACHE modifier if you're going to run it multiple times with a view toward measuring performance.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE whatever FROM whatever WHERE whatever
```

Even if you do this, you won't get useful data by repeating the same query over and over again.  Why not?  Even if your tables are enormous, MySQL will bring lots of the data needed to satisfy the query into memory.  If you do this on a quiet system, you're almost guaranteed to get better performance the second time you run the query as the first time.

To answer your question about starting the query multiple times: that's how you run it multiple times. If you're trying to assess performance, you need to include the time it takes to receive, parse, plan, and execute the query.

(Some other DBMS makes and models offer prepared statements that somehow cache  the parsed, planned, and ready-to-execute queries, in some sort of compiled form. Not MySQL).

If you run the query on a busy system once an hour or so, you'll get a better estimate of the query's timing.

Note well:  The 90th percentile of query performance is a more valuable measure than the average.  Most queries, when used multiple times, run pretty well. But sometimes they hang up (due to other traffic on the system and such) and the 90 percentile tells you about those outlying bad performers.

Comment: plan is to run query on dedicated server, database will have around 10milion record, i want to first measure avg time for queries without indexed rows, after that with indexed rows, and to make exact in MongoDB and to make comparison between results in MySQL and MongoDB

Comment: Thousands upon thousands of developer years have been, and still are being, spent to make it difficult to get valid results from the repeated measurements you suggest. Those developers are doing "optimization." So be careful drawing economic conclusions from your results.